# The trace map in étale cohomology

Tags: traces, six-operations

Trace has a pretty formal definition in a monoidal closed category in which $[V, V] \cong V^* \otimes V$ as the composition $\mathbb{Tr} : 1 \rightarrow [V, V] \cong V^* \otimes V \rightarrow 1$, where the $\cong$ is the presupposed right inverse to the canonical map $V^* \otimes V \rightarrow [V, V]$.

In étale the cohomology of a variety over an algebraically closed field, the Künneth theorem and poincare duality, along with several properties of the characteristic class $\text{cl}$ are enough for a Lefschetz fixed point theorem and to establish the six functor formalism.

I was wondering if there is a formal reason to expect $\mathbb{Tr}$ to arise as the counit $\epsilon : f f^! \rightarrow \text{Id}$, given perhaps a product rule for $f^!$?

It might go something like this:

$$\langle f f^!  ab, 1 \rangle_{C} \stackrel{\alpha}{=} \langle f^! ab, f^! 1 \rangle_{B} \stackrel{\beta}{=} \langle f^! a f^! b, f^! 1 \rangle_{B} \stackrel{\gamma}{=} \langle f^! a ,f^! b \rangle_{B} \stackrel{\delta}{=} \langle a, b \rangle_{A}$$

where

- $\alpha$ arises from push forward and Poincare duality
- $\beta$ is multiplicativity of $f^!$.
- $\gamma$ is cyclicity of trace.
- $\delta$ is ???
- $A$ is the étale cohomology ring of variety $X$ over algebraically closed field $k$.
- $B$ is the étale cohomology ring of the point $*$ with global sections $\mathcal{O}(*) = k$. Note: I suspect this formalism should generalize perfectly well to the relative case.
- $C$ is ???

Comment: $f^!$ is not multiplicative... anyway your question is bizarrely telegraphic. But you might want to look at Lu-Zheng: https://arxiv.org/abs/2005.08522